# Learning JS - How do you retrieve a value from a key/value pair, when that pair is itself a value of another pair, all within an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

Ok, so I'm learning JS and I have hit a bit of a wall. I apologize if I use the wrong terms to describe any of this but...

In the code below, I need to check within the 'people' array - within 'location' (would location be considered a key here?) - retrieve the value of 'state' (key/value as the value of a key???) - and check if it is or is not a certain 'state'. I have to check this for each person in the 'people' array.

I know how to check if the value of 'state' is what I need it to be or not (once I can actually get to that value), but I can't seem to get that deep into it. I know I need a loop that pulls the value of 'state' from within 'location' from within 'people',  but I don't know how to begin to write that.

```js
const people = [{
    location: {
        street: 'B Street',
        state: 'New Hampshire',
        country: 'United States',
        city: 'New Douglas'
    },
    last_name: 'Schumm',
    first_name: 'Tom',
    contacts: {
        mobile: '(904) 730-4211',
        email: 'deep_shakira@hotmail.com'
    }
},
{
    location: {
        street: 'Pennsylvania Avenue',
        state: 'Hawaii',
        country: 'United States',
        city: 'Woodland'
    },
    last_name: 'Jacobson',
    first_name: 'Reyna',
    contacts: {
        mobile: '1-968-545-2264',
        email: 'type_leta@yahoo.com'
    }
},
{
    location: {
        street: 'Cottage Street',
        state: 'Connecticut',
        country: 'United States',
        city: 'Glaslyn'
    },
    last_name: 'Zemlak',
    first_name: 'Maxwell',
    contacts: {
        mobile: '1-407-135-6122',
        email: 'dorthy@hotmail.com'
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to filter the array based on matching value of state ? or you just want true/false if the state exist in array or not ?

Comment: @Sarfraaz In the end, I will be filtering a much longer array of people/information. Basically, if they are NOT from Alaska or Hawaii, that person will be pushed into a new array. I know how to accomplish that part, I am simply struggling to get the value of 'state' while in its current location.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the array and using . notation get the state values. You can use an if condition to check for a specific state

```js
const people = [{
    location: {
      street: 'B Street',
      state: 'New Hampshire',
      country: 'United States',
      city: 'New Douglas'
    },
    last_name: 'Schumm',
    first_name: 'Tom',
    contacts: {
      mobile: '(904) 730-4211',
      email: 'deep_shakira@hotmail.com'
    }
  },
  {
    location: {
      street: 'Pennsylvania Avenue',
      state: 'Hawaii',
      country: 'United States',
      city: 'Woodland'
    },
    last_name: 'Jacobson',
    first_name: 'Reyna',
    contacts: {
      mobile: '1-968-545-2264',
      email: 'type_leta@yahoo.com'
    }
  },
  {
    location: {
      street: 'Cottage Street',
      state: 'Connecticut',
      country: 'United States',
      city: 'Glaslyn'
    },
    last_name: 'Zemlak',
    first_name: 'Maxwell',
    contacts: {
      mobile: '1-407-135-6122',
      email: 'dorthy@hotmail.com'
    }
  }
]
people.forEach(e => {
  if (e.location.state == 'Connecticut') {
    console.log(e.first_name + " " + e.last_name)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

Filter the array of persons based on the value inside the location.state of each object inside array,

You can improve the matching condition for states based on your preference, [like, comparing after converting all to lowercase & trim spaces]
, but that's totally depending on the requirement that you have

```js
var people = [{
    location: {
        street: 'B Street',
        state: 'New Hampshire',
        country: 'United States',
        city: 'New Douglas'
    },
    last_name: 'Schumm',
    first_name: 'Tom',
    contacts: {
        mobile: '(904) 730-4211',
        email: 'deep_shakira@hotmail.com'
    }
},
{
    location: {
        street: 'Pennsylvania Avenue',
        state: 'Hawaii',
        country: 'United States',
        city: 'Woodland'
    },
    last_name: 'Jacobson',
    first_name: 'Reyna',
    contacts: {
        mobile: '1-968-545-2264',
        email: 'type_leta@yahoo.com'
    }
},
{
    location: {
        street: 'Cottage Street',
        state: 'Connecticut',
        country: 'United States',
        city: 'Glaslyn'
    },
    last_name: 'Zemlak',
    first_name: 'Maxwell',
    contacts: {
        mobile: '1-407-135-6122',
        email: 'dorthy@hotmail.com'
    }
}];

let states = ['Alaska','Hawaii'];

var filtered = people.filter( person => states.indexOf(person.location.state) > -1 );

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const people = [{
        location: {
            street: 'B Street',
            state: 'New Hampshire',
            country: 'United States',
            city: 'New Douglas'
        },
        last_name: 'Schumm',
        first_name: 'Tom',
        contacts: {
            mobile: '(904) 730-4211',
            email: 'deep_shakira@hotmail.com'
        }
    },
    {
        location: {
            street: 'Pennsylvania Avenue',
            state: 'Hawaii',
            country: 'United States',
            city: 'Woodland'
        },
        last_name: 'Jacobson',
        first_name: 'Reyna',
        contacts: {
            mobile: '1-968-545-2264',
            email: 'type_leta@yahoo.com'
        }
    },
    {
        location: {
            street: 'Cottage Street',
            state: 'Connecticut',
            country: 'United States',
            city: 'Glaslyn'
        },
        last_name: 'Zemlak',
        first_name: 'Maxwell',
        contacts: {
            mobile: '1-407-135-6122',
            email: 'dorthy@hotmail.com'
        }
    }];
const test1 = people.find(people => people.location.state === 'Connecticut');
console.log(test1);
```

You can use single statement to search:

```
const test1 = people.find(people => people.location.state === 'Connecticut');
```